# How do I define a type for an array of unique objects, with some types only existing once and some being required

Tags: typescript

Something like:

```
interface TypeA {
  id: 'type_a';
  // a unique type structure
};

interface TypeB {
  id: 'type_b';
  // a unique type structure
}; 

interface TypeC {
  id: 'type_c';
  // a unique type structure
};

// many more types in the array

type AnArray = Array<TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | ...>;
```

Also... AnArray must contain one of TypeA can only contain one of TypeB and can contain multiple of TypeC

so this would be invalid due to having no TypeA

```
const a: AnArray = [
  {
    id: type_b,
    // ...
  }
];
```

This would be invalid due to having mulitple TypeB

```
const a: AnArray = [
  {
    id: type_a,
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: type_b,
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: type_b,
    // ...
  }
];
```

And this would be valid even though it contains multiple TypeC

```
const a: AnArray = [
  {
    id: type_a,
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: type_b,
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: type_c,
    // ...
  },
  {
    id: type_c,
    // ...
  }
];
```

Comment: If the order is known you could use a tuple. A and B will always be at 0 and 1 positions?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Unfortunately the order is unknown

Comment: Then only runtime check

Comment: "AnArray must contain one of TypeA can only contain one of TypeB and can contain multiple of TypeC" is somewhat ambiguous.  I assume  it means: • Exactly one TypeA must be present in the array • Exactly one TypeB must be present in the array • Zero or more TypeC must be present in the array.  If I got some of that wrong, please [edit] the question to clarify what you mean, preferably using precise language like "exactly one", "one or more", "zero or more", etc.

Comment: There is no *specific* type in TypeScript corresponding to your requirement.  You can write a *generic* type that verifies if a particular type meets your requirement and then use a generic helper function to validate array literals.  So instead of `const a: AnArray = [...]` you'd write `const a = asAnArray([...])`.  If that works for you, and if I understand your requirements, you can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mb0K9w) for example.  I can write up an answer if this addresses your question fully; if not, what am I missing?